# How to solve the system of two equations to get the approximation value

Tags: equation-solving

I'm a Ph.D. student in Banking and Finance and I'm not familiar with the solving system of equations. I don't know how to solve the two equations below to get the approximation value of x, and y. All other parameters are given. N is standard normal distribution function with mean 0 and variance 1. Could you please help me? If anyone knows how to use Stata to solve it, please let me know too?

$$xN(y) - be^{-rd}N(y-k\sqrt{7.5})- a = 0$$
$$y - \frac{\ln(\frac xb) + 7.5\left(r + \frac{k^2}{2}\right)}{\sqrt{7.5}k} = 0 $$

In particular, we have $b=10511$, $r=0.0479$, $k=0.237$, $a = 60.67$ and $d=9$.

Thank you very much.
Best regards,
Phoebe

Comment: Could you please write the equations in a clear format? They look cluttered and are difficult to understand what the variables are.

Comment: My second equation is: y - (ln(x/B)+(r+(F^2)/2)*7.5)/F*sqrt(7.5) = 0

Comment: Sorry, this is the first time I use this website, I can't enter to type 2 equations together ^_^

Comment: My first equation is: x*N(y) - B*exp(-C*D)*N(y - F*sqrt(7.5))-A = 0. I would like to solve to find x and y in these two equations. Many thanks Tugrul.

Comment: You may want to write the equations in a readable format such as `N(y)=Normal distribution of variable y.` For example, what is `Fsqrt` and what is `F`. If you write them in such clean format, people might want to give you feedback.

Comment: Thanks Tugrul ^^

Comment: Thank you very much because of correcting the equations for me ^^.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is no indication that a copy of *Mathematica* is even available to the OP.

Answer (score 1):

This is the beginnings of an answer.

First we need to translate your equations into Mathematica format. The rule here is that symbols defined in Mathematica begin with a capital letter. Thus your D has a special meaning (derivative). Therefore we need to replace your capitals with lowercase letters. These won't clash with other symbols.

Second the standard normal distribution function includes a mean and standard deviation. Are these known or are they further unknowns?  I would call this function f[y] but you already have a f so I will cause this g[y]. Note that function parameters are given in square brackets.

Thus I think your equations are

```
eqns = {
  x g[y] - b Exp[-c d] g[y - f Sqrt15/2]] - a == 0,
  y - (Log[x/b] + (r + (f^2)/2)15/2)/(f Sqrt[15/2]) == 0
  }
```

Note that there is a difference in "=" and "==" ; the first assigns the second is a symbolic equals. I have also changed your 7.5 to 15/2 because Mathematica can work in whole numbers.

What are your unknowns here? There are two equations and thus you can solve for two unknowns. I guess x and y are unknowns. Is this correct?

With this assumption we can write

```
  sol=Solve[eqns,{x,y}]
```

We get this back

> During evaluation of In[12]:= Solve::ifun: Inverse functions are being used by Solve, so some solutions may not be found; use Reduce for complete solution information.
>
> During evaluation of In[12]:= Solve::svars: Equations may not give solutions for all "solve" variables.
>
> {{x -> 
>          b E^(1/4 (15 f^2 - 30 r + 2 Sqrt[30] f (-Sqrt[(15/2)] f + y)))}}

This is two warning messages and an attempt to make x the subject of the equation.

I suspect there is no simple solution to these equations. Do we have values for the parameters? 
Hopefully you see how we are progressing. If you had been using pencil and paper this is about how far you would have got. What else would you have tried without using a computer?

I hope this helps.

**Edit**

With the edit to the original question things are getting clearer we can now write

```
ClearAll[f, b, r, k, a, d];
f[y_] := Exp[-y^2/2 ]/Sqrt[2 π ]

eqns = {
   x f[y] - b Exp[-r d] f[y - k Sqrt[15/2]] - a,
   y - (Log[x/b] + (r + (k^2)/2) 15/2)/(k Sqrt[15/2])
   };
eqns // TraditionalForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Here I started by defining the normal distribution as a function of f. Then I input the two equations without the "==" part. Now we define the values we know for the parameters.

```
vals = {b -> 10.511, r -> 0.0479, k -> 0.237, a -> 60.67, d -> 9};

eqns2 = eqns /. vals
```

First we explore ranges of values for x and y that make the equations zero. We do this by plotting.

```
Plot3D[eqns2[[1]], {x, -100, 500}, {y, -10, 10}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now we can plot values where both equations are zero. We do this by plotting the contours where the above `Plot3D` is zero.

```
ContourPlot[eqns2 == {0, 0}, {x, -100, 500}, {y, -10, 10}, 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Unfortunately the contours do not cross so there is no solution. Are your parameters correct? If you change them you may find some solutions to your equations.

**Edit 2**

The poster now thinks that one of the values should be b = 10511. So now we do

```
vals = {b -> 10511, r -> 0.0479, k -> 0.237, a -> 60.67, d -> 9};
eqns2 = eqns /. vals;
Plot3D[eqns2[[1]], {x, -100, 10000}, {y, -10, 10}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

In this range we have a zero contour. The contour plot looks like

```
ContourPlot[{eqns2[[1]] == 0, eqns2[[2]] == 0}, {x, -100, 
  10000}, {y, -10, 10}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Zooming in a bit gives

ContourPlot[{eqns2[[1]] == 0, eqns2[[2]] == 0}, {x, 2000, 
  6000}, {y, -2, 10}, PlotRange -> All]

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So the curves cross at about {3300, -1}. These values can be used to guide a root finding exercise.

```
FindRoot[eqns2, {x, 3300}, {y, -1}]
```

> {x -> 3303.88, y -> -0.905076}

So that is your answer. {3303.88, -0.905076}

Comment: Many thanks Hugh ^^

Comment: Dear Hugh, I have just edited the parameter b=10511. I have around 3000 observations. I get parameters of the first observation as an example to see whether we can solve it out or not. Again, thanks so much for helping me.

Comment: Did you not realise that you are on the software site for Mathematica? This is not a maths site but a site that  discusses how the software Mathematica can be used. If you look at my answer I have provided all the code you would need to write. Mathematica is set up to solve your sort of problem with only a few lines of code. Clearly you can solve your problems using Mathematica.

Comment: Thank you very much Hugh. You make my Ph.D. life a little bit better now ^_^.

Comment: @PhoebeVu This is a site for helping people who have mathematica solve their problems. It is not a site where people do the work for you. If you get a copy of mathematica and then get stuck trying for yourself then I will help you. We help people with mathematica problems not people with problems in general.

Comment: Dear Hugh, I get it. Thank you very much for your help. I appreciate that.